# Not able to align fields in column in VF page

Tags: visualforce, style, stylesheets

Can anyone please help me with styling. I even tried panelgrid and pageblock section item but nothing is working

My current page image:
[image]

VF page :

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
             <apex:actionRegion >
               <span class="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap  first">Account Name </span>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.AccountId}">
                 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!some}"
                            rerender="panel1">

                            <apex:param assignTo="{!abc}" value="{!Opportunity.AccountId}" />
                            </apex:actionSupport>

                   </apex:inputField>
             </apex:actionRegion>

             <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
             <apex:outputLabel >{!$ObjectType.Opportunity.fields.abc__C.Label}</apex:outputLabel>
             <apex:outputPanel id="uuo" >
              <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.JUST__C}" />

             </apex:outputPanel></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

             <apex:inputfield value="{!Opportunity.Name}" />

                    <apex:outputPanel >
                        <apex:actionRegion >

                       <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!ABCD}">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!optionabc}"/>
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="nd"/>
                </apex:selectList>  </apex:actionRegion>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
               </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: Throwing `<span>` tags in randomly sure doesn't help. You should have `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>` as a direct descendent of `<apex:pageBlockSection>`...

Comment: @AdrianLarson thanks for your response I tried that way but its not working there is no change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actionRegion is causing the field to get screwed up. To get proper alignment, place each field as a direct child of pageBlockSection.

```
<apex:actionRegion >
    <apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.AccountId}">
             <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!some}" rerender="panel1">
                 <apex:param assignTo="{!abc}" value="{!Opportunity.AccountId}" />
             </apex:actionSupport>
         </apex:inputField>
     </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:actionRegion>
```

Most of your other stuff falls under this same advice. If you need finer granularity with your actionRegion, you can use a pageBlockSectionItem:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:outputLabel>Account Name</apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:actionRegion>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.AccountId}">
                 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!some}" rerender="panel1">
                     <apex:param assignTo="{!abc}" value="{!Opportunity.AccountId}" />
                 </apex:actionSupport>
             </apex:inputField>
         </apex:actionRegion>
     </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
 </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

I recommend the first approach when possible for the best results/least amount of work.